# How come the images arent loading properly?

Tags: images

The images on our wordpress site recently stopped loading. All you see is a broken image box like such.. www.theloftycsei.org.

Any assistance in remedying the issue would be greatly appreciated as we are a charity and hiring a developer is slightly out of our means at the current time..

Comment: Are we supposed to be looking at www.theloftycsei.org, that doesn't appear to be a valid domain name?

Comment: I think it is http://www.loftycsei.org/

Comment: It isn't all of your images that fail to load. Looks to me like the problem is with the images that load via timthumb. Is that script up-to-date?

Comment: Apologies it is loftycsei.org. They were working a week ago and suddenly no longer load. Im not sure if the issue is in the script as we havent changed anything since then.

Answer (score 1):

The site's Adress should be http://www.loftycsei.org/.

You got a Problem in your `timthumb.php`, it is delivered with your Theme.

It uses a deprecated Function on Line 549, `ereg`. The Problem is that when your image is processed, it outputs the deprecated warning before sending the Headerinformation for the Contents being a JPG.

You got various methods of fixing this.

I would suggest steering away from using Timthumb due to security issues, and using custom Image sizes for your website, everything can be done using the WordPress built in functions.

Another possible solution would be disabling the deprecated warnings:

in your `php.ini`

```
error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

or while running your scripts:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

You can also run the deprecated function minus the error handling.

But as I already mentioned, I would build the theme NOT based on timthumb.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help.. I will give this a shot and let you know what how it goes..

Comment: Sidenote,,, thanks for the prompt response, this site is fantastic!